# Why is cast required for interface?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create an instance against an interface but it fails with a cast conversion error.

The following simple scenario works fine.

```
class Employee:IEmployee
{
  public Employee (int Id) {}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

interface IEmployee
{
  string Name {get;set;}
}
```

//Execute

```
IEmployee employee = new Employee(1)
```

I have larger classes where the same scenario isn't working.  Mainly they are just larger classes.  I get the compile time error below:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'IDirector' to 'Director'.  An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Instead of the above type of syntax, I have to use this:

```
IDirector myDirector = (IDirector)new Director(directorId);
```

Director does implement IDirector.  These are single objects and not list to single objects.

It also doesn't work if I pass an interface in through the class constructor and try to assign it to a class type that implements the interface:

```
private ClassB classb;

Public ClassA (IClassB classbInterfaceInstance)
{
  classb = classbInterfaceInstance;
}
```

Any idea why the cast is needed in some cases but not others?

Comment: Does `Director` directly implement `IDirector`, or simply provide a conversion operator?

Comment: It implements the interface.

Comment: This is because you forgot to implement `IDirector` inside `Director` :-)

Comment: you should post the Director class. Possibly scaled down, but still with the problem.

Comment: I think this is weirdness with Visual Studio.  I had two instance for different classes where this was occurring.  After a few builds onc instance of the error went away.  After another build all is fine for this project.  I built the solution and that works now too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign an interface instance to its driven class. there is a deep concept but i show it in simple example.

Consider this interfaces and the class code:

```
interface IClassA 
{
   int MemOfA;
}

interface IClassB
{
   int MemOfB;
}

class MyClass : IClassA,IClassB
{
   int MemOfA;
   int MemOfB;
}
```

now in some code block we define an instance of class `MyClass`(Considering the `iIClassA` is an instance of interface `IClassA`):

```
MyClass a = iIClassA; // error !
```

Why error?

how we can set the member of `IClassB` in the `MyClass` ? however if the `MyClass` would implement just `IClassA` again we couldn't do it! because again may be the `IClassA` inherits multiple interfaces.

Comment: That isn't what I'm doing.  It's the other way around.  Issue seems to have been something odd with VS.NET rather than a code error.

Comment: then show what you are doing? edit your question and explain it!

Answer (score 0):

```
private ClassB classb;

Public ClassA (IClassB classbInterfaceInstance)
{
  classb = classbInterfaceInstance;
}
```

It is impossible to get this code working. Remember: ClassB implements IClassB. So ClassB is always IClassB. 
But think about the following scenario:
You have got an interface: IClassB. And there are 2 classes - ClassB1 and ClassB2. Both implement IClassB.

```
interface IClassB {}
class ClassB1 {}
class ClassB2 {}

IClassB foo = new ClassB2();
ClassB1 = foo; //this can not work. Because you are trying to cast ClassB2 to ClassB1
```

Take a look at my code. This is exactly what you are doing:

```
private ClassB classb;
//workaround 1)
private IClassB classb;

Public ClassA (/*workaround 2)*/ ClassB /*instaed of IClassB*/ classbInterfaceInstance)
{
  //remember that classbInterfaceInstance can be ClassB2, ClassB3, ... what ever. But you are casting it into ClassB.
  classb = classbInterfaceInstance;

  //possible workarounds:
  // 1) make the "classb" field of type "IClassB" (see above)
  // 2) change the type of the classbInterfaceInstance parameter to ClassB
  // 3) try to cast the parameter (see code below)

  //workaround 3)
  if(classbInterfaceInstance is ClassB)
  {
    classb = (ClassB)classbInterfaceInstance;
  }
}
```